# Deep Learning on Nvidia 1070 Ti Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I'm pulling my hair out at this point, I've spent a ton of time trying different things to get my card working to use Tensorflow.

My *latest* attempt (which has similar problems to before) was that I tried installing the tensorflow docker

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/
```

I installed the nvidia-docker and ran the SMI and it seemed to report back that my GPU exists.

Then I ran this command

```
nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

After downloading and starting up, I try running the notebooks, (first the hello tensorflow notebook).

As soon as I try to "import" tensorflow (just using the default unmodified notebook) I get a KernelRestart.

```
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

I'm not really sure what the next best step is, I don't know how to troubleshoot docker containers, and then inside that the jupyter notebook.

I've had similar issues previously while attempting to run locally without a docker container.

Any suggestions on what a good next step is? I spent more than I cared to on this card and am out of ideas on how to get it to work.

(I believe I could import locally on my machine using tensorflow-gpu installed, however when I got to a conv2d section I would get could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED if I'm recalling, but it's been a few hectic days)

Edit: Yes to cuda and cudnn and i apt get installed nvidia-390, it *seemed* like a good test was nvidia-smi which works. I just finished compiling tf from scratch and still failling (in this case, importing tf doesnt fail, but same not initalized error, and perhaps not the right nvidia version it mentioned, and called out nvidia-390.77 i think)
Im considering a fresh 18.04 install and an earlier nvidia-3xx version install, attempting to 'downgrade' resulted in broken apt, and multiple days of trying to fix

EDIT2 :
I also came to the realization I installed CUDA 9.0, but the cudnn7.1 with 9.1 CUDA (you can download from nvidia that combo whatever that means).
I'm attempting to revert, but I am having plenty of trouble backing out, I'm extremely close to just wiping and re-installing ubuntu and going from there. I have all the commands and think it might be easier, but I'm not sure if that will solve it. (eg cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1)

EDIT3 : 
Came back to respond to this. I wrote up a gist of what I had to do to get my GPU working in ubuntu 16.04 for my main machine, however I didn't test it in docker, here is the gist of it.

https://gist.github.com/onaclov2000/c22fe1456ffa7da6cebd67600003dffb

Copy pasting here:

```
# 1070 Ti
Fresh Install 16.04
(download updates, and include 3rd party)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
# Contents
sudo bash -c 'cat >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf << 'EOF'
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
EOF'
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
# Takes about 30-40 minutes 1.5GB approx
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/secure/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
    No to install nvidia accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux
    yes to Cuda 9.0 toolkit
    default
    yes to symbolic link
    yes to samples
    default location is fine


#Alternately (need to test)
#sudo sh cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run --silent --toolkit --samples

cat >> ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64\
${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
EOF
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
make
./deviceQuery # Assuming make was successful
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/bandwidthTest
make
./bandwidthTest # Assuming make was successful
# Look for Result = PASS

sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

# Couldn't find on 16.04 maybe this is a 18.04 upgrade?
#sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-9.0 cuda-command-line-tools-9-0

# At this point the driver and CUDA are installed, now it's time to install the CUDNN driver/piece.
#This is the link that I have, be sure to use v7 not v7.1 as I haven't had luck in the past with that (though it might work).
https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7
# 333 MB so will take a bit
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
cd cuda
sudo cp lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp include/* /usr/local/cuda/include/

sudo apt-get install git tmux
cd ~/Downloads
# At this point I'm going to install Anaconda
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -O anaconda-install.sh 
bash anaconda-install.sh # Follow Prompts adding path to bash
source ~/.bashrc
conda create --name ml
source activate ml
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5

# test the install
cd ~
mkdir projects
cd projects
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models




# Addional notes
Run a sample from the cuda samples folder

/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
make
./deviceQuery

Output:

Plenty but ends with the following
deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 2
Result = PASS


This tells you which cudnn is installed

cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2

Outputs:
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 1
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 4
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION    (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)


# This tells you what

nvcc --version 

Outputs:

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

Finally, I updated to 18.04 but haven't chased all this down again, so I will update with a 18.04 version at the gist above as I move forward.

Comment: Have you installed `cuda` and `cudnn`?

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia proprietary drivers? Does the card work for anything else? Is there a test to see if the card is running properly without tensorflow?

Comment: Check your cuda version. The latest tensorflow version requires cuda 9, cudnn 7+, ubuntu 16.04.